# sql / linq to entities: group on group of hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

i have a table with snow data which i get delivered per hour.
so for instance at between 0am and 1 am 1 cm snow will fall, between 1 am and 2 am 3 cm snow will fall, between 2 am and 3 am 0 cm snow will fall, between 3 am and 4 am 2 cm snow will fall etc.
so the table has a Snowdate column (datetime), a Snowdate hour column (int) and a snowfall column (int)
now i want to present the data grouped by groups of 6 hours (0-5, 6-11, 12-17 and 18-23), so when between 0 am and 6 am i have 6 records (1cm, 3c, 0cm, 2 cm, 2cm, 0cm) i want to show one row with the number 8, and so on for the rest of the day.
For every hour a day there will be a record in the db, so always 24 records a day

A pure sql solution will be ok (a view or so) or a linq to entities  will be ok too.

Michel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correct, try something like this

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        SnowDate DATETIME,
        SnowHour INT,
        SnowFall INT
)

INSERT INTO @Table (SnowDate,SnowHour,SnowFall) SELECT '10 Sep 2009', 0, 1
INSERT INTO @Table (SnowDate,SnowHour,SnowFall) SELECT '10 Sep 2009', 1, 3
INSERT INTO @Table (SnowDate,SnowHour,SnowFall) SELECT '10 Sep 2009', 2, 0
INSERT INTO @Table (SnowDate,SnowHour,SnowFall) SELECT '10 Sep 2009', 3, 2
INSERT INTO @Table (SnowDate,SnowHour,SnowFall) SELECT '10 Sep 2009', 4, 2
INSERT INTO @Table (SnowDate,SnowHour,SnowFall) SELECT '10 Sep 2009', 5, 0
INSERT INTO @Table (SnowDate,SnowHour,SnowFall) SELECT '10 Sep 2009', 6, 10
INSERT INTO @Table (SnowDate,SnowHour,SnowFall) SELECT '10 Sep 2009', 7, 10


SELECT  SnowDate,
        CAST(FLOOR((SnowHour) / 6.) * 6 AS VARCHAR(4)) + ' TO ' + CAST((FLOOR((SnowHour) / 6.) + 1) * 6 - 1 AS VARCHAR(4)),
        SUM(SnowFall) AS Total
FROM    @Table
GROUP BY    SnowDate,
            FLOOR((SnowHour) / 6.)
```

Answer (score 3):

Group by the hour / 6 (using integer arithmetic) and select for grouping the amount column.  Select into a new object, the Key * 6 and Sum() the resulting grouping for the total for that "hour".  The "hour" will be the first hour in each range.

```
var query = db.SnowRecords.GroupBy( s => s.SnowHour / 6, a => a.SnowFall )
                          .Select( g => new {
                            Hour = g.Key * 6,
                            Amount = g.Sum()
                           });
```

You don't say if you need to group by date as well, but if you do, then this would become the inner query on the records grouped by date.

```
var query = db.SnowRecords.GroupBy( s => s.SnowDate.Date )
                          .Select( g => new {
                                Date = g.Key,
                                HourlySnowFall = g.GroupBy( s => s.SnowHour / 6, a => a.SnowFall )
                                                  .Select( sg => new {
                                                      Hour = sg.Key * 6,
                                                      Amount = sg.Sum()
                                                   })
                           });
```

Comment: thanks for your solution, but i find them hard to read sometimes, the lambda things. I've done some with simple ones, but in this case it is easier for me to read the sql.